# Is it possible to read the entire memory of a PHP-process?

Tags: php

How can I access directly from PHP the raw memory and/or the symbol table?

The reason why I would like to do that is b/c then I could search the memory/table for strings to find out about where certain process have been triggered and strings are loaded.

I guess I could use Reflection, but that would be more complicated I think, cause the information is structured and I would have to parse the entities instead of just using a RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access directly from PHP the raw memory and/or the symbol table?

In short: Not possible.

> I guess I could use Reflection, but that would be more complicated I think, cause the information is structured and I would have to parse the entities instead of just using a RegEx.

That is, by the way, more reliable than regular expressions.

Comment: Why would that be more reliable if the very string is unique?!

Comment: In _very_ large structures is critical to assume, that anything is unique enough, that it is distinguishable from everything else, especially if the content changes from time to time. At least I wouldn't like it very much, if I must rely on it ;)

Comment: it's not about relying and having astronauts depending on it while they are on a moon-mission ... it's just about debugging flexibly ...